# Mock file with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, jestjs

I can not create a json file with a mock with jest in node.js.

I tried this :

```
const mock = require('mock-fs');
mock({
    'test.json': [{ 'name':'John', 'age':30, 'car':null }]
});
```

but that does not work, he does not like the arguments put in content for the file.

Do you have an idea of ​​how? Thank's

Comment: do you want to mock `fs`?

Comment: I want create a virtual json file with contents. With fs or others, I want just create that

Answer (score 0):

Modified the gist found above to be used in jest:

Add this to your **jest.setup.js**:

```
// mock file
class MockFile {
  constructor ({ name = 'mock.jpg', size = 1024, type = 'image/jpg', lastModified = new Date() }) {
    var blob = new Blob(['a'.repeat(size)], { type })
    blob.lastModifiedDate = lastModified

    return new File([blob], name)
  }
}

global.MockFile = MockFile
```

Use it in your test like this:

```
const mockFile = new MockFile({ 
  name: 'testFile',
  type: 'image/jpg',
  size: 512
})
```

Answer (score -1):

So here is a sample test case for that. Not sure if you have figured it out, but here is what I used. This is in typescript but you could convert that to js

```
import mock from 'mock-fs';
import pump from 'pump';
import * as util from 'util';
const fileReadPromisfy = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

....
describe('Test suite for bucket functionality', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        mock({
            'sample-file.txt': 'Content of the sample file',
            'sample-upload.txt': '',
        });
    });
test('test mock fs', async (done) => {
        pump(fs.createReadStream('sample-file.txt'), fs.createWriteStream('sample-upload.txt'));
        fileReadPromisfy('sample-upload.txt')
            .then((data) => {
                expect(fs.readFileSync('sample-upload.txt')).toBeDefined();
                done();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove additional libraries being imported when trying to help OP. In this case ` pump` and `util` aren't visible and add extra complexity.